# How to make C++ scoped_lock or C# lock() that works for both C# and C++ in WinRT

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, windows-runtime

I am making a program that has a C++/CX WinRT core library, with a C#/XAML application layer. I need to make some kind of mutex/critical_section/lock() to prevent multiple threads from wreaking typical multithreaded madness on some resources of a class defined in the C++ library.

Note that both the C++ and C# sides can be accessing the resources that need to be locked, so I need some kind of interface that works for both.

The C++ code I started with (The WinRT DirectX sample) uses critical_section, but this cannot be directly exported, nor can scoped_lock, as they aren't WinRT compatible (i.e. ref and sealed)

I made a simple C++/CX class that worked like scoped_lock (i.e. lock in constructor, unlock in destructor) but given the unpredictability of when the destructor is called in C#, that didn't work for obvious reasons.

What I have right now is just manual Lock() and Unlock() methods on the class that contains the resources, it then calls lock() or unlock()on a critical_section object, and it works, but it lacks the elegance and clarity of either the scoped_lock class or C#'s lock keyword.

Ideally I'd prefer to use C#'s lock keyword to lock the class (or lock some member of the class) but my search-fu is not showing me any examples of how to set up the C++ class to also lock on the same object.

Comment: Have you tried to implement ICloseable in your C++/CX object?  It maps to the *using* statement in C#, the compiler will automatically call your Close() method at the end of the scope block.

Comment: It appears to be even simpler than that. Just by declaring a public destructor in the C++ object, a C# _using_ block will call the destructor on exit of the block, making it work exactly how I wanted. Thanks for the tip, as it definitely pointed me in the right direction.